# Ubuntu 12.04, Tomcat7, NetBeans 7 - getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/slf4j/Logger;

Tags: maven, tomcat7, slf4j

I have a Java EE project, which is working fine in one of our remote servers with tomcat container. Whenever we want to make some changes to our application, we do it on our local machine, then build it and copy the `ws.war` on the server in the root of the tomcat.

I want to setup the local development environment where I can make the changes to the application. I have the project source files with me. I did following things:

```
 1. Install tomcat7 in my home directory and set up `CATALINA_HOME`
    environment variable in `.bashrc`
 2. Install oracle-java and setup JAVA_HOME in `.bashrc`
 3. Install Netbeans 7 and import the project in it.
 4. Since, the Netbeans came with `glassfish` as default server, I added
    a tomcat as the server with proper configuration.
 5. I try running the application (through Netbeans), and I receive the following error:

Jun 04, 2013 2:39:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
  2 INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/        lib:/usr/lib
  3 Jun 04, 2013 2:39:59 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
  4 INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
  5 Jun 04, 2013 2:39:59 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
  6 INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
  7 Jun 04, 2013 2:39:59 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
  8 INFO: Initialization processed in 1100 ms
  9 Jun 04, 2013 2:39:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
 10 INFO: Starting service Catalina
 11 Jun 04, 2013 2:39:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
 12 INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.40
 13 Jun 04, 2013 2:39:59 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
 14 INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/frrole/apache-tomcat-7.0.40/conf/Catalina/localhost/ws.xml
 15 Jun 04, 2013 2:39:59 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
 16 WARNING: A docBase /home/frrole/apache-tomcat-7.0.40/webapps/projectfrrole/target/ws inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored
 17 Jun 04, 2013 2:40:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
 18 SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 19 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ws]]
 20     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
 21     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
 22     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
 23     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
 24     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
 25     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1636)
 26     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
 27     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
 28     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
 29     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 30     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 31     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
 32 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/slf4j/Logger;
 33     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
 34     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2317)
 35     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1762)
 36     at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
 37     at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:261)
 38     at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:140)
 39     at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)
 40     at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:405)
 41     at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
 42     at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
 43     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
 44     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
 45     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5269)
 46     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 47     ... 11 more
 48 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger
 49     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
```

I did some research and I found out that there's some version incompatibility with 1.6.1 version and previous versions of `slf4j`. However, I'm not able to find a fix for this.

Any help is appreciated. My POM.xml is as following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.frrole.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>ws</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>frrole web service</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <springframework-version>3.0.5.RELEASE</springframework-version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>
                        WEB-INF/lib/*spring*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/*common*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/*http*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/*connector*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/*json*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/*jackson*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/*aspect*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/*aop*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/*c3p*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/*jta*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/*4j*.jar
                    </packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>mm.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mm.mysql</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of 'mvn dependency:tree' command for your project?

Comment: did you try to deploy normally, without using netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it's a bit odd you have sl4fj-log4j12 but not the actual log4j dependency itself. Typically you need this as sl4fj is just a facade. Try adding something like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Secondly, you might want to check what's inside $TOMCAT_HOME/lib folder in your production server. If any additional jars placed there on top of the default, you will need to copy that to your local environment too (or restructure the deployment so everything is contained in your app)

Comment: Okay, will try that and will let you know.

Comment: Now, I'm getting ... Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/slf4j/Logger;

Comment: declaring a dependency on org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12 will pull in org.slf4j:slf4j-api as well as log4j:log4j. Thus, there is usually no need to declare org.slf4j:slf4j-api or log4j:log4j separately.